# open pop up modal in mvc and angular js project

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

I'm working on Project MVC, Angular js
I have a problem that I show modal and in initiate fun i load a number of questions on the basis of user choose his subject and then opening the pop up modal with questions
But I do not know the modal open but without any questionds 
at first i Load skill page and from this page user select his subject and then popup modal opened 
after search i think the  problem because of modal loaded when skill page load so after open modal no questions appeared 
how can i reload modal or solve this problem 
Hint : when pass function in init with values it worked and questions appeares but when pas values values passes aright and beduge is correct but popup open as empity 
For example
ng-init =" ReadQuizQuestions (11, true)"
working good but when 
ReadQuizQuestions (secItem.Id, secItem.hasQuiz) not working
can any one help me to solve this problem

in skill page

```
       <div class="badge_unit heading_font video_course_preview" ng-
        click="ReadQuizQuestions(secItem.Id,secItem.hasQuiz)"></div>
```

in angular js file

```
$scope.ReadQuizQuestions = function (id,hasQuiz) {
if (hasQuiz == true) {
ShowPleaseWait();
QuizService.ReadQuiz(QuizId).success(function (res) {
.
.
.
 .......
$('#QuizModal').modal('show');
        });

        HidePleaseWait();

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In this exemple i passed parameters from my controller to the modal (list of questions)

To pass the parameter you need to use resolve and inject the items in controller of modal.

```
$modal.open({
    emplateUrl: 'myModal.html',
    controller: 'ModalDialogController', 
       resolve: {
          questionsList: function () {
          return $scope.questionsList;
       }
    }
   })
   .result.then(function(result) {
       alert(result);
   });
```

After selecting your question and validate i reyrn the selected value to my controller with

```
$scope.ok = function () {
   $modalInstance.close($scope.modal.selectedName);
};
```

[This is a full exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/hamedit4pme/t8os73rq/6/)